# computed value setter on a component

Tags: ractivejs

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/xwLk2vb0/

```
Person = Ractive.extend({
  template: "<p>the person named {{name}}</p>",
  computed: {
      name: {
          get: function(){
              if(typeof(this.get('_name'))=='undefined'){return "nameless"}
              else{return this.get('_name')}
            },
          set: function(val){
              this.set('_name',val)
            }
      }
  }
});

people_model = new Ractive({
  el: '#people_container',
  template: '{{#people}}<person/>{{/}}',
  data: {
    people: [{},{},{}]
  },
  components :{person : Person}
});

people_model.set('people.0.name','Spongebob')
```

I can't understand why the last line doesn't invoke the setter on the 'name' computed attribute and then update the rendered templates. Can someone offer any insight, please.

thanks in advance

Comment: it would be helpful to me to understand why the downvotes and 'close' votes. There must be something about SO that I haven't understood

Comment: I don't understand it either, it's a perfectly reasonable question. Maybe someone fat-fingered. I gave you an upvote to help redress the balance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that computed properties are 'owned' by the component on which they live; you can't interact with them via their parent. I wrote a bit about why that's the case [here](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1805#issuecomment-80613808) - it doesn't exactly describe your situation, but the fact is that there's no mapping between the `Person` component's `name`, and the `name` property of the object it relates to. `name` is effectively shadowed.

This is a Good Thing insofar as it makes code easier to follow and reason about - if an object were populated with additional values just because they coincided with computed properties on a component (i.e, each object in the `people` array would suddenly get a `name: 'nameless'` property), you could easily end up in a brain-bending situation trying to figure out where some data came from in your app.

So the solution is to have a 'proxy' computed property that acts as an accessor for the real `name` property, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/muoz44ec/. Note that we're explicitly linking `name` inside the component to `this.name` on the person object.

Comment: Thanks, Rich, for the helpful response, thanks for the upvote, and thanks for ractivejs!